# Can boost variants safely be used with pointers to forward declared classes?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

Can boost variant safely accept pointers to classes that are forward declared without any unintended implications such as using them with [visitors](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html)?

```
class A;
class B;

typedef boost::variant<A*, B*> Variant;

class A {
public:
    A() {}
};

class B {
public:
    B() {}
};
```

Comment: What does prevent you from attempting this to compile?

Comment: @S.M. It compiles fine, but I'm wondering if it's a good idea to use pointers within variants

Comment: The you need to explain what you mean by "safely". "Safely accept" looks like to be compiled successfully.

Comment: @S.M. Although I agree that the question is overly abstract, I think I can sense the usual application where the need arises. So, I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the builtin recursive element support for this exact purpose. It makes the (de)allocation(s) automatic and exception safe.

Here's a complete demo where `B` actually recursively contains a `vector<Variant>` (which is 90% of the use-cases for forward-declared element types):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/555e00fe04e60231)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
struct A;
struct B;

typedef boost::variant<A, B> Variant;

struct A {
    int solution = 42;
};

struct B {
    std::string answer = "Thanks for all the fish!";
    std::vector<Variant> other { A{1}, A{2}, B{"Three", {}}, A{4} };
};

struct Visitor {
    std::string indent = " - ";
    void operator()(Variant const& v) const {
        boost::apply_visitor(Visitor{"  " + indent}, v);
    }
    void operator()(A const& a) const { std::cout << indent << a.solution << "\n"; };
    void operator()(B const& b) const {
        std::cout << indent << std::quoted(b.answer) << "\n";
        for (auto& v : b.other) {
            operator()(v);
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    Variant v;
    v = A{};

    boost::apply_visitor(Visitor{}, v);

    v = B{};
    boost::apply_visitor(Visitor{}, v);
}
```

Prints

```
 - 42
 - "Thanks for all the fish!"
   - 1
   - 2
   - "Three"
   - 4
```

Comment: I just realized that by leveraging `std::vector`'s modern support for incomplete types, I didn't actually (need to) showcase `boost::recursive_wrapper` (or the `recursive_variant_` meta type placeholder). For examples see [many of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20recursive_wrapper) or the ["advanced usage" section in the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive)